# Difference in logics in average functions

Tags: python, spyder

I just started learning python. I was looking at some course and while calculating the average of numbers, they are using below logic

Course logic

```
def aver_age1(num_bers):
    su_m = 0
    for i in range (0, len(num_bers)):
        su_m = su_m + num_bers[i]
        print(num_bers[i])
    average = su_m/len(num_bers)
    print("average is", average)
```

But I used other logic that I feel its simple and easy. Not sure what is the difference between them

My Logic

```
def aver_age(num_bers):
    su_m = sum(num_bers)
    le_n = len(num_bers)
    me_an = su_m/le_n
    print("The sum of numbers is", su_m)
    print("The length of numbers is", le_n)
    print("The average of numbers is", me_an)
```

Comment: It's the same thing, they don't use the `sum` function (probably because it hasn't been discussed), but it does the same thing. Also, what's up with your naming scheme?

Comment: Yours is better (except your variable names). They probably wanted to teach `sum` at a later stage.

Comment: e.g. in the second example you cannot `print` (or do some other logic) with partial results

Comment: They are the same, both divide a total by a count, but the course is probably trying to get you used to iterating a `range` function... how would you implement a sum if you could not call `sum(list)`?

Comment: Great for the inputs. But @Selcuk, May I know what is the best way to name the variables?

Comment: @Vinayprakash There is no "best way" but I would at least make them readable. Also see PEP-8 for some pointers.

Comment: You can refer to the following doc for the naming convention. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: @Vinayprakash There is no point using variable name `num_bers` - that is just difficult to read (call it `numbers`). You should avoid using `sum` because that is the name of a builtin function, but if you want to call something it close to `sum` then `sum_` would be the normal choice. Or you could call it `total` or something.

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. All makes sense. :)  I will work on naming the variables

Comment: Purely for the sake of ‘what else is out there’ another way to calculate is: `numpy.array(num_bers).mean()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is essentially an abstraction over what is happening in the code by your course's page. You are using an inbuilt [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function that will essentially function by aggregating all the values in the array. This is exactly what you get by summing each value together like your course code.